# How to display correct format data while exporting excel in php?

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am using matwebsite package for downloading excel file it's downloaded perfectly but some of the columns values are displayed in other format  `(1244+67866)`(Note:- which records are more letters at that time it's displaying like this ),How to resolve this error please help me to fix the issue..

```
class BooksExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithEvents, ShouldAutoSize
{

    protected $data = null;
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return collect($this->data);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Object',
            'Id',
            'Return date',
            'status',
         'amount'
        ];
    }


    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class    => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                // All headers - set font size to 14
                $cellRange = 'A1:E1';
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize(12);

                // Apply array of styles to B2:G8 cell range
                $styleArray = [
                    'borders' => [
                        'outline' => [
                            'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
                            'color' => ['argb' => 'FFFF0000'],
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

`my downloaded excel`

```
object      id          return-date         status         amount  
Book1       345         24-01-2020          returned       98+99 // original is ==> 9898989

Book2       543         22-01-566           done           1425
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign formats to columns this way:

In your Export class in the export directory you have to implement a method such as:

```
public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
          'A' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER,
          'B' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DATETIME,
          'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
          'D' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
          'E' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
          'F' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER,
        ];
    }
```

You can do all kinds of formats, just type `NumberFormat::` and scroll through all the possibilities

Comment: A column is for string type at that time what should i do

Comment: @user17426459 what do you mean? I think on their website is a documentation with all the possibilities explained

Comment: i tried with your solution i have original data is `6666666666666666666` but the output is `6666666666660000`

Comment: then have a look into the documentation of this library. I am not here to give you the perfect solution, just a hint in the right direction